# Generating pairs of additive and multiplicative factors for integers

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, number-theory, factorization, partitions

Given an integer $n$, I want to get two lists:

> a) the set of pairs of the divsors $a,b$ into exactly two factors $n=a\cdot b$,
>
> b) the set of pairs $a,b$ of two summands $n=a+b$.

The code I came up with works, but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient/elegant or even build in alternative:

```
  Function[ int, {#,int/#}& /@ Divisors[int]][12]

  Function[ int, {#,int-#}& /@ Range[int -1]][12]
```

Also, in case I want to do that later, how do I eliminate lists from a list, which only differ in order, e.g. how do I reduce `{{a,b},{b,a}}` to `{{a,b}}` ?

(Side note: These problems arise in writing the code for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14883/generating-a-function-which-outputs-possible-chemical-reactions) bigger problem)

Comment: Have you seen `IntegerPartitions[]`?

Comment: Since the answers below are from nearly a decade ago: Has Wolfram since introduced a built-in for product pairs?

Comment: @theorist Asking here you probably reach nobody but me and I don't know.

Comment: I thought the others who answered might be notified of my comment on your post, but perhaps that's not how the notifications work here.

Comment: Pretty sure you only get a notification if it's under your post/writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a)**

We can pass through the first half of the list of divisors to avoid duplicating factors. There are many possible ways to proceed, let's mention a few of them :

```
f1[n_] := {#, n/#} & /@ First @ Partition[ #, Ceiling[ Length[#]/2] ] & @ Divisors[n]
```

or

```
f2[n_] := Module[{k, l}, k = Divisors @ n; l = Length @ k;
                         Table[{k[[i]], k[[l + 1 - i]]}, {i, Ceiling[l/2] }] ]
```

or a completely different (less efficient) approach :

```
f3[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Solve[x y == n && 0 < x <= y, {x, y}, Integers][[All, All, 2]]
```

e.g.

```
f1[37900003]
And @@ (f1[#] == f2[#] == f3[#] & /@ Range[100, 200])
```

> ```
> {{1, 37900003}, {19, 1994737}, {131, 289313}, {2489, 15227}}
> True
> ```

**b)**

Let's point out three different ways, using various `Mathematica` functions, respectively `IntegerPartitions`, `FrobeniusSolve` and `PowersRepresentations` :

```
g1[n_Integer /; n > 0] := IntegerPartitions[n, {2}]
g2[n_Integer /; n > 0] := FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, n]
g3[n_Integer /; n > 0] := PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 1]
```

All these functions yield outputs in different forms; `g2`, `g3` include zeros, in `g2` the ordering is valid, e.g.

```
g1[15]
```

> ```
> {{14, 1}, {13, 2}, {12, 3}, {11, 4}, {10, 5}, {9, 6}, {8, 7}}
> ```

```
g2[15]
```

> ```
> {{0, 15}, {1, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 10}, {6, 9}, {7, 8},
>  {8, 7}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}, {11, 4}, {12, 3}, {13, 2}, {14, 1}, {15, 0}}
> ```

```
g3[15]
```

> ```
> {{0, 15}, {1, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 10}, {6, 9}, {7, 8}}
> ```

We can get rid of `0`, e.g. wrapping `g2` or `g3` in `DeleteCases`, e.g. :

```
DeleteCases[ g3[15], {___, 0, ___}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 10}, {6, 9}, {7, 8}}
> ```

A more general approach is [`PowersRepresentations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowersRepresentations.html)`[n,k,p]`, which gives the distinct representations of the integer `n` as a sum of `k` non-negative `p` -th integer powers, e.g. `PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 3]` gives all possible natural pairs `{a,b}` satisfying :  $\; a^3+b^3 = n $, e.g. :

```
PowersRepresentations[855, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> {{7, 8}}
> ```

indeed `7^3 + 8^3 == 855`.

Using `g1` or `g3` we needn't to eliminate sets which only differ in order, anyway one can use `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union`, e.g. :

```
Union[{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}, {b, a}, {a, c}}, SameTest -> (Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &)]
```

and

```
DeleteDuplicates[{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}, {b, a}, {a, c}}, Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &]
```

yield :

> ```
> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For part (b) of your question, there is a built-in function:

```
  IntegerPartitions[12, {2}]
  (* {{11, 1}, {10, 2}, {9, 3}, {8, 4}, {7, 5}, {6, 6}} *)
```

For the last part,

```
 deDup1 = DeleteDuplicates[#, #1 == Reverse@#2 &] &;
 (* or *)
 deDup2 = DeleteDuplicates[#, Union@#1 == Union@#2 &] &;
 deDup1@Function[int, {#, int/#} & /@ Divisors[int]][12] 
 (* {{1, 12}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}} *)
```

**Update:**  and for part (a) - big thanks to @Rojo for the idea - you can use:

```
divPairsF1 = Divisors[#] /.
  d_ :> Transpose @ MapAt[ Reverse,
                           Partition[d, Sequence @@ Through @ {Ceiling, Floor}[Length@d/2]],
                              1  ] &; 
 (* or *)
divPairsF2 = Thread[{#[[;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]], 
               Reverse[#[[1 + Floor[Length[#]/2];;]]]}] &[Divisors[#]] &;
 (* or *)
divPairsF3 =DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ (Thread[{#, Reverse[#]}] &@Divisors[#])) &;

divPairsF1[12]
 (* {{1,12},{2,6},{3,4}} *)
```

Comment: cool, can it also produce the flipped sets, e.g. $\{2,10\}$?

Comment: You could also rely on the `Divisors` ordering and do something like `Divisors[int]/.d_:>Transpose@MapAt[Reverse, Partition[d, Length@d/2], 2]`

Comment: `IntegerPartitions` gives the partitions in reverse-lex order. To get a list including the `flipped` sets, you can use `Join @@ ({#, Reverse /@ #} &[
    IntegerPartitions[12, {2}]]) // DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: @Rojo, thank you, great idea. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for my code, but one should beware of the cases with odd number of divisors. Perhaps changing to `Partition[d, Sequence @@ Through@{Ceiling, Floor}[Length@d/2]]`, or in your version, adding a `Ceiling` to the first `Span` and a `Floor` to the second

Comment: @Rojo, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For product pairs you might use:

```
pp = Thread[{#, Reverse@#}][[ ;; Ceiling[Length@#/2] ]] & @ Divisors @ # &;
```

This is several times faster than your construct on my machine.

You may also be interested in [this function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2342) which is a generalization of this to *n* products.

For additive pairs [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) has already been recommended.