# Generating a list of all factorizations

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory, factorization

What is the best way to generate a list of all factorizations of some number $n$? I'm quite new to Mathematica so this might be obvious. I have been trying some basic stuff with `For`-loops and `FactorInteger` and `Divisors` but I'm not really getting anywhere. There must be some elegant way of doing this. An example of the result I'm after, for $n=60$:

$$\{\{2,2,3,5\}, \{4,3,5\}, \{2,6,5\}, \{2,3,10\}, \{2,2,15\}, \{12,5\}, \{2,30\}, \{3,20\}, \{4,15\}, \{6,10\}, \{60\}\}.$$

Comment: How about [this](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/contents/Factorizations/Factorizations_2.html)?

Comment: You might have to be more clear about what you are after. For example, why isn't `{6,10}` on your list but `{2,6,5}` is? Or should it be?

Comment: @CameronMurray: yes of course, you're right, I missed that one.

Comment: @cormullion: That's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @cormullion I just started reading (thanks); I hope it doesn't make my answer appear to silly after the fact.

Comment: Related [Generating pairs of additive and multiplicative factors for integers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15094/generating-pairs-of-additive-and-multiplicative-factors-for-integers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function from the article that cormullion linked is shorter and faster than what I proposed below.  Transcribed in terse style:

```
uf[m_, 1] := {{}}
uf[1, n_] := {{}}
uf[m_, n_?PrimeQ] := If[m < n, {}, {{n}}]
uf[m_, n_] := uf[m, n] =
  Join @@ Table[Prepend[#, d] & /@ uf[d, n/d], {d, Select[Rest@Divisors@n, # <= m &]}]
uf[n_] := uf[n, n]

uf[60]
```

> ```
> {{5, 3, 2, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {6, 5, 2}, {10, 3, 2}, {10, 6}, {12, 5}, {15, 2, 2},
>  {15, 4}, {20, 3}, {30, 2}, {60}}
> ```

---

I propose this:

```
ClearAll[f, f2, div]
mem : div[n_] := mem = Divisors@n
mem : div[n_, k_] := mem = # ~Take~ Ceiling[Length@#/k] &@div@n

f[n_, 1, ___] := {{n}}
mem : f[n_, k_, x_: 2] := mem =
  Join @@ Table[If[q < x, {}, {q, ##} & @@@ f[n/q, k - 1, q]], {q, n ~div~ k}]

f2[n_Integer] := Join @@ Table[f[n, i], {i, Tr@FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]]}]
```

The function `f2` finds all factorizations as requested:

```
f2[60]
```

> ```
>  {{60}, {2, 30}, {3, 20}, {4, 15}, {5, 12}, {6, 10}, {2, 2, 15}, {2, 3, 10},
>     {2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 3, 5}}
> ```

It is quite fast:

```
f2[1080^2] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.109, 16434}
> ```

The function `f` (upon which `f2` is written) efficiently finds the factorizations of `n` of length `k` with a minimum factor of `x`:

```
f[60, 2, 5]
```

> ```
> {{5, 12}, {6, 10}}
> ```

It is optimized with memoization as described [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/list-of-integer-factorization-into-n-terms).  It can be written without memoization (as shown there) to use less memory but computation will take longer.