# Multiplicative partition function

Tags: function-construction, number-theory

I am trying to create a multiplicative partition function that would generate something like

```
f[12]
(*{{2, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {6, 2}}*)
f[24]
(*{{2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 6}, {4, 2, 3}, {8, 3}, {12, 2}, {4, 6}}*)
f[48]
(*{{2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 6}, {4, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 12}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 4, 6}, 
{4, 4, 3}, {6, 8}, {4, 12}, {3, 16}, {2, 24}}*)
```

I have got as far as

```
n = 30;
i = FactorInteger[n];
r = Range[Length[i]];
Join[{f = Flatten[Map[Table[i[[#]][[1]], {x, 1, i[[#]][[2]]}] &, r]]},
Transpose[{d = DeleteDuplicates[f], Map[n/d[[#]] &, Range[Length[d]]]}]]
```

but it is turning out to be more complicated than I thought. Is there a more efficient way of tackling this?

## Update

Have got a little further, but still missing some:

```
n = 48;
i = FactorInteger[n];
r = Range[Length[i]];
f = Flatten[Map[Table[i[[#]][[1]], {x, 1, i[[#]][[2]]}] &, r]];
p = Drop[Drop[DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[f]], 1], -1];
d = Split[Drop[Drop[Reverse[Divisors[n]], 1], -1]];
Drop[Map[Sort[Join[p[[#]], d[[#]]]] &, Range[Length[d]]], -1]
```

Comment: Looked at that but can't see how that would help? Also looked at Combinatorica package - will keep going ...

Comment: Please see the Mathematica Journal article on factorizations by Knopfmacher and Mays, volume 10, number 1. They give code to find multiplicative partitions, and counts of the numbers of such partitions. A similar question has been asked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25431/generating-a-list-of-all-factorizations).

Comment: Thank you! Lots of choice now for further exploration :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly more compact form of *belisarius*'s answer (differs in that factors are pooped out in descending order of maximum factor in a set):

```
f2[x_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Map[Times @@ # &, 
    SetPartitions[Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[x]]], {2}]]
```

Tiny bit more efficient, but really in the noise - both are probably about as efficient as is reasonable: You'd have to prevent creation of duplicate subsets (for later multiplication) to improve much, and I'd venture doing that would eat more time than just using them and deleting dupes post-hoc...

As to your comment question:
[A001055](https://oeis.org/A001055)

```
ClearAll[c, r, ds, n, a];

c[1, r_] := c[1, r] = 1;

c[n_, r_] := 
  c[n, r] = 
   Module[{ds, i}, ds = Select[Divisors[n], 1 < # <= r &]; 
    Sum[c[n/ds[[i]], ds[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[ds]}]];

a[n_] := c[n, n];

(* count *)
a[1000]

(* calculate and get length to verify *)
Length@f2[1000]

(*

31
31

*)
```

*Vastly* faster for large *n* than calculating fully...

Update: Poking around [A162247](https://oeis.org/A162247)

```
g[lst_, p_] := 
 Module[{t, i, j}, 
  Union[Flatten[
    Table[t = lst[[i]]; t[[j]] = p*t[[j]]; 
     Sort[t], {i, Length[lst]}, {j, Length[lst[[i]]]}], 1], 
   Table[Sort[Append[lst[[i]], p]], {i, Length[lst]}]]]; 

f[n_] := Module[{i, j, p, e, lst = {{}}}, {p, e} = 
   Transpose[FactorInteger[n]]; 
  Do[lst = g[lst, p[[i]]], {i, Length[p]}, {j, e[[i]]}]; lst];

f[12]

(* {{12}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 2, 3}} *)
```

But *much* faster on larger numbers than f2 (but still not as fast as count-only...)

Comment: Great - it is getting shorter & shorter! BTW, is there any way of counting the number of multiplicative partitions without actually calculating them?

Comment: eg `n = 12; Length[f2[Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]]]`

Comment: @martin: see update. There's probably a faster way than this, but it's plenty fast...

Comment: Great :) - still struggles with large n but I presume `Divisors` is the limiting function - don't think I can overcome that!!

Comment: @martin: Check update - faster way to get full results.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for the digging! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm over-complicating it. Anyway:

```
<< Combinatorica`
f[x_] := DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort /@ Flatten[
    Apply[Times, (SetPartitions /@ 
       Flatten /@ 
        Tuples[Flatten[{#[[1]]^IntegerPartitions@#[[2]]} & /@ 
           FactorInteger[x], 1]]), {3}], 1]]}

f[24] // Column
(*
{24}
{3,8}
{4,6}
{2,12}
{2,3,4}
{2,2,6}
{2,2,2,3} 
*)
```

Comment: Wow - this is great - my head was really starting to ache!!

Comment: Well, OP's example lacks of `{24}`.

Comment: @Kuba **And** {2, 2, 6}

Comment: @ Kuba, I thought that if I include 1 as factor things might get a little awkward ...

Comment: @martin Don't feel the urge to accept. I'm sure it can be done much more efficiently.

Comment: That is very noble!! I will keep it back for a day or 2 & see what comes up then ...:)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation that performs very similarly to ciao's `f`. It's a recursive approach using memoization. Maybe someone can see a clever way to speed this up some more...?

```
MultiplicativePartitions[1] := {{1}}
MultiplicativePartitions[x_] := MultiplicativePartitions[x] = 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   If[PrimeQ[x],
    {{x}},
    Flatten[
     Prepend[
      Table[(Flatten[{#, x/i}] & /@ MultiplicativePartitions[i]), {i, 
        Divisors[x][[2 ;; -2]]}],
      {{x}}
      ],
     1]
    ],
   Sort
   ]

MultiplicativePartitions[12]
```

> {{12}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 2, 3}}

Calculation the multiplicative partitions of all numbers up to $n$ for $n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 50000$ (clearing the memoized values each time), the timings for this and ciao's `f` are very similar:

[image]

I don't hold out much hope for scaling my solution to $n \gg 10000$ as the scaling of `Divisors` is no better...!