# How to find all prime power factorizations of an integer

Tags: functional-style, number-theory, code-review, coding-style

I want to put in $n$ and get the possible factorizations into prime powers. Let's say for 24 I want `{{8,3}, {4,2,3}, {2,2,2,3}}`.

The algorithm for doing this on paper is this:

1. Find the prime factorization of $n$. Example case: $24=2^3 \cdot 3$
2. Take powers and find their partitions. Example case: $3=2+1=1+1+1$ and $1$.
3. Construct the different factorizations of $n$. Example case: $24=8\cdot3=4\cdot2\cdot3=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3$.

My code is this:

```
primeFactorsWithPowers = FactorInteger[n];
primeFactorsWithPartitionedPowers = {#[[1]], IntegerPartitions[#[[2]]]} & /@ primeFactorsWithPowers;
primePowerFactors = #[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ primeFactorsWithPartitionedPowers;
factorizationsIntoPrimePowersRaw = Tuples@primePowerFactors;
factorizationsIntoPrimePowers = Flatten /@ factorizationsIntoPrimePowersRaw
```

For `n = 360` this gives `{{8, 9, 5}, {8, 3, 3, 5}, {4, 2, 9, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 9, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}}` which is correct. But it seems a bit long and clumsy to have so many obscure operations for this. Being a badass I attempt to wrap it all in a function:

```
primePowerFactorizations[n_] := Map[Flatten, #[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ Map[{#[[1]], IntegerPartitions[#[[2]]]} &, FactorInteger[n]] //Tuples]
```

or maybe:

```
primePowerFactorizations[n_] :=
 Map[Flatten,
  Tuples[
   #[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@
    Map[{#[[1]], IntegerPartitions[#[[2]]]} &,
     FactorInteger[n]]]]
```

Either way it looks like something that I will never be able to read again. Can I write this in a nicer way? Maybe you know of a method or function that allows to shorten this?

I don't understand how multiple uses of `/@`, `@`, `//` are supposed to work. For me a nice way to see the order of operations (and unwrap it with my eyes) would seem if I could write it like this:

```
primePowerFactorizations[n_] :=
 Flatten /@
  Tuples @
   #[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@
    { #[[1]], IntegerPartitions[#[[2]]] } & /@
     FactorInteger[n]
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Comment: `Either way it looks like something that I will never be able to read again` Well, welcome to programming in Mathemtica :)  I once spend one hr trying to understand few lines of code in Mathematia book written by one of the experts in Mathematica. I could not figure how the code works. So I gave up.  To make code easier to understand, I would break it in pieces. do not tail-call too many functions. I would keep the limit to 2 calls and at most 3.  So instead of   `f1[f2[f3[f4[x]]]]` you would write `y=f4[x]` and `y=f3[y]` and `y=f2[y]` and so it. you get the idea.

Comment: @Nasser how do you wrap such code into a function while keeping the in-function code written step by step?

Comment: Look up `Module[]` and other scoping constructs; see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559) for some guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possibility, which I'll decompose into separate steps for your easier perusal:

```
n = 360;
pow = ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]
   {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5}}

facs = Table[Times @@@ Internal`PartitionRagged[#, part],
             {part, IntegerPartitions[Length[#]]}] & /@ pow
   {{{8}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{9}, {3, 3}}, {{5}}}

Flatten[Tuples[facs], {{1}, {2, 3}}]
   {{8, 9, 5}, {8, 3, 3, 5}, {4, 2, 9, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 3, 5},
    {2, 2, 2, 9, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}}
```

---

The first step is to generate the expanded prime factorization from the output of `FactorInteger[]`. Recall that it returns a list of factors in the format `{prime, power}`. Using `ConstantArray[]` with level-1 `Apply[]` (`@@@`) performs that expansion by converting, say, `{2, 3}`, into `ConstantArray[2, 3]`, which evaluates to `{2, 2, 2}`, and applying that transformation to each prime-power pair.

The second step is a bit tricky, and uses the *undocumented* function `` Internal`PartitionRagged[] ``, which you can read about [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83124). For each expanded factor, we generate the set partitions by first partitioning the length with `IntegerPartitions[]`, and then using `` Internal`PartitionRagged[] `` to convert these into explicit set partitions. For instance,

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1}]
   {{2, 2}, {2}}
```

Following up with `Times[]` + level-1 `Apply[]` turns it into explicit factors (for the previous example, `{4, 2}`).

The final step is a useful blend of `Tuples[]` and `Flatten[]`. `Tuples[{list1, list2, (* stuff *)}]` will explicitly generate tuples whose elements are selected from each of the given inner lists, as noted in its documentation. The final use of `Flatten[]` is slightly advanced, and is discussed in further detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119); suffice it to say that it rearranges the output of `Tuples[]` so that you end up with a list of lists of factors.

Comment: I learned a lot here! Still it seems that every line of Mathematica code needs a couple lines worth of comments :) Maybe I am saying that just because I couldn't manage to understand flatten-with-matrix thing but isn't that unnecessary? I mean we just need to flatten each of tuples like `{{4,2},{3,3},{5}}`. Would `Flatten/@Tuples[facs]` be any worse?

Comment: Mapping `Flatten[]` will also work, yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[m_, n_] := m^# & /@ n
func[n_] := 
 Join @@@ Tuples[
   f @@@ Cases[
     FactorInteger[n], {x_, y_} :> {x, IntegerPartitions[y]}]]
```

e.g.`func[360]` yields:

```
{{8, 9, 5}, {8, 3, 3, 5}, {4, 2, 9, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 9, 
  5}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}}
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `Flatten /@ Tuples[Power @@@ MapAt[IntegerPartitions, FactorInteger[n], {All, 2}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Nice. I will leave as a constructive comment :)

Answer (score 3):

The general problem of multiplicative partitions is discussed on Stack Exchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48601/multiplicative-partition-function) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25431/generating-a-list-of-all-factorizations). Adapting code from the [article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/contents/Factorizations/Factorizations_2.html) by Knopfmacher and Mays gives the following function `mpp`. It is initially slower than the other answers given here but, when used repeatedly, the memoization speeds subsequent solutions.

```
mpp[1, m_] := {{}}
mpp[n_, 1] := {{}}
mpp[n_?PrimeQ, m_] := If[m < n, {}, {{n}}]

mpp[n_, m_] := mpp[n, m] =
   Flatten[
     Table[Map[Join[{d}, #] &, mpp[n/d, d]],
           {d, Pick[#, UnitStep[m-#], 1] &[Select[Divisors[n],PrimePowerQ]]}],
   1]

mpp[n_] := mpp[n, n]
```