# Finding vampire numbers

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

How to find [vampire numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VampireNumber.html) by using *Mathematica*?

> A number $v=xy$  with an even number $n$ of digits formed by multiplying a pair of $n/2$-digit numbers (where the digits are taken from the original number in any order) $x$ and $y$ together.

For example:

```
    1.    1260=21*60
    2.    1395=15*93
    3.    1530=30*51
    4.    1827=21*87
```

I tried to find all the 4 digit vampire numbers:

```
FindInstance[{1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d == (10 m + n) (10 l + k), 
a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, m > 0, n > 0, k > 0, l > 0, 
{a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k} ∈ Integers,
{m, n, l, k} ∈ {a, b, c, d}}, 
{a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k}]
```

but there is an error message

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Vampire Numbers that the OP refers to are a simple case of a more general problem of expressing numbers in terms of their own digits ... sometimes called Narcissistic Numbers.

Why write 1296 when you can write:

[image]

For a classification of these different types (including vampire Numbers), see for instance:

http://www.tri.org.au/numQ/pwn/comparison.html

Some years ago, I played around with these structures in *Mathematica*, and wrote a fun little paper on it for the *Journal of Recreational Mathematics* (volume 33(4), 2004-2005, pp.250-254) on generalising these structures to includes radicals and factorials etc, which I called: *Pretty Wild Narcissistic* Numbers, or Numbers that PWN.

For the Vampire case, for any 4 digit number `abcd`, the possible permutations into 2 and 2 numbers are:

```
perm2 = Map[ Partition[#,2]&, Permutations[{a,b,c,d}]];
```

The 24 possible products of those couplings are:

```
tes[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] = Map[ Times@@(Map[FromDigits, #, 1])&, perm2]
```

> {(10 a + b) (10 c + d), (10 a + b) (c + 10 d), (10 a + c) (10 b + 
>       d), (10 a + c) (b + 10 d), (10 b + c) (10 a + d), (b + 
>       10 c) (10 a + d), (a + 10 b) (10 c + d), (a + 10 b) (c + 
>       10 d), (10 b + c) (10 a + d), (10 b + c) (a + 10 d), (10 a + 
>       c) (10 b + d), (a + 10 c) (10 b + d), (a + 10 c) (10 b + d), (a + 
>       10 c) (b + 10 d), (b + 10 c) (10 a + d), (b + 10 c) (a + 
>       10 d), (10 a + b) (10 c + d), (a + 10 b) (10 c + d), (10 b + 
>       c) (a + 10 d), (b + 10 c) (a + 10 d), (10 a + c) (b + 10 d), (a + 
>       10 c) (b + 10 d), (10 a + b) (c + 10 d), (a + 10 b) (c + 10 d)}

The following takes 0.09 seconds to solve:

```
Cases[
 ParallelTable[If[ MemberQ[ tes[IntegerDigits[i]], i], i],  {i, 1000,9999}], _Integer] 
// AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.090674, {1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880}}

Answer (score 14):

Consider the trusty `DivisorPair` [function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15094/generating-pairs-of-additive-and-multiplicative-factors-for-integers) from MrWizard:

```
DivisorPairs[n_] := Thread[{#,Reverse[#]}][[;;Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]]&[Divisors[n]]
```

`DivisorPairs` returns pairs of divisors multiplying together to form `n`. From these, select those pairs with both divisors having half the number of digits of `n`. Then check that the sorted digits of `n` match the sorted digits of one or more of the remaining divisor pairs.

```
VampireNumberQ[n_]:=
   Block[{m, d, p},
      m = IntegerLength[n]/2;
      d = Sort[IntegerDigits[n]];
      p = Select[DivisorPairs[n], IntegerLength[#] == {m, m} &];
      Select[p, Sort[Flatten[IntegerDigits[#]]] == d &] =!= {}
   ]
SetAttributes[VampireNumberQ,Listable]
```

`VampireNumberQ` is about 6 times faster than the OEIS `fQ`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[With[{r = Range[1000, 9999]}, Pick[r, VampireNumberQ[r]]]]
```

> {0.227699, {1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880}}

Comment: May you include the link to MrWizard's `DivisorPairs` function in your post so it displays as referenced in the links on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 8):

Since `FindInstance` willl not give us the whole solution set I prefer to use `Solve`:

```
{a, b, c, d} /. 
Solve[ Or @@ ({1000, 100, 10, 1}.{a, b, c, d} == (10 #1 + #2)(10 #3 + #4)& @@@ 
       Permutations[{a, b, c, d}]) && And @@ Thread[1 <= # <= 9 &@{a, b, c}]&&
       0 <= d <= 9, {a, b, c, d}, Integers]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 6, 0}, {1, 3, 9, 5}, {1, 4, 3, 5}, {1, 5, 3, 0},
>   {1, 8, 2, 7}, {2, 1, 8, 7}, {6, 8, 8, 0}}
> ```

Comment: +1 for the concept, but you need additional conditions to ensure that the digits `{m, n, l, k}` are a permutation of the digits `{a, b, c, d}`.  This is why `FindInstance` returns 1116 even though it is not a vampire number -- notice how it used 36*31.  The additional conditions are something like `Or @@ Thread[
  FromDigits[{a, b, c, d}] == 
   FromDigits /@ Permutations[{m, n, l, k}]]`.  It may take longer to solve :)

Comment: but there are only seven 4 digit vampire numbers $1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880$

Comment: @WReach Thanks for pointing out the problem (I haven't grasped at first sight what the OP expects),  in fact, a direct addition of your conditions are not recommended, however  a slight modification works fine.

Comment: Nice simplification.  I'd +1 again if I could :)  Should the digit constraints be `1 <= a <= 9 && 0 <= {b, c, d} <= 9` in the more general case?

Comment: @WReach That's right, however more efficient approach would be `Select[1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d /. 
  Solve[Or @@ ({1000, 100, 10, 1}.{a, b, c, 
           d} == (10 #1 + #2) (10 #3 + #4) & @@@ 
       Permutations[{a, b, c, d}]) && 0 <= {a, b, c, d} <= 9, {a, b, 
    c, d}, Integers], # > 1000 &]`  The more diverse logical conditions we apply the more time `Solve` takes.

Answer (score 6):

I found the code at [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/A014575)

```
fQ[n_] := 
If[OddQ@IntegerLength@n, False, 
MemberQ[Map[Sort@Flatten@IntegerDigits@# &, 
Select[Map[{#, n/#} &, TakeWhile[Divisors@n, # <= Sqrt@n &]], 
SameQ @@ Map[IntegerLength, #] &]], Sort@IntegerDigits@n]];
```

and it's quite fast

```
Select[Range[10^5], fQ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\{1.96896,\{1260,1395,1435,1530,1827,2187,6880\}\}$

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) to define the region for `Element` ([`∈`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)).

From `Element`'s documentation note that you need to specify one of the possible domains or provide a region. A list of integers is neither but you can create a one-dimensional region specification using `Interval`. For example,

```
NumberLinePlot[Interval[{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There `Interval` defines a one-dimensional region that contains numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. One point to note is that when specifying the element of a one-dimensional region you must provide a 1D vector, `{2}`, and not a scalar, `2`.

Next note that your constraints are incomplete. You need `0 < a <= 9` and the remainder `0 <= x <= 9`.

We also need to ensure that all the numbers `{a, b, c, b}` are used exactly once. The `Sort` constraint sees to this.

You may use the fourth parameter of `FindInstance` to return more than one.

Taking this into account and making use of short-hand equivalents for the constraints we get.

```
res =
 FindInstance[
  {
   1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d == (10 m + n) (10 l + k),
   0 < a <= 9,
   0 <= {b, c, d, m, n, l, k} <= 9,
   {a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k} ∈ Integers,
   {{m}, {n}, {l}, {k}} ∈ Interval @@ Map[{#, #} &, {a, b, c, d}],
   Sort@{a, b, c, d} == Sort@{m, n, l, k}
   },
  {a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k},
  4]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 6, d -> 0, m -> 6, n -> 0, l -> 2, k -> 1}, 
>    {a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 5, m -> 3, n -> 5, l -> 4, k -> 1}, 
>    {a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> 3, d -> 0, m -> 3, n -> 0, l -> 5, k -> 1}, 
>    {a -> 6, b -> 8, c -> 8, d -> 0, m -> 8, n -> 0, l -> 8, k -> 6}}
> ```

Then check your answers.

```
1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d == (10 m + n) (10 l + k) /. res
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as I discussed in my comment on @Artes answer -- 9801 is not a vampire number, and the product being used is 99*99.

Comment: @WReach See update.

Comment: That's better.  But for reasons that are not immediately apparent to me, it is not finding 1395, 1827 or 2187.

Comment: why there are only four solution  `Solve[{1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d == (10 m + n) (10 l + k), 0 < a <= 9,
   0 <= {b, c, d, m, n, l, k} <= 
   9, {a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k} \[Element] 
   Integers, {{m}, {n}, {l}, {k}} \[Element] 
   Interval @@ Map[{#, #} &, {a, b, c, d}], 
  Sort@{a, b, c, d} == Sort@{m, n, l, k}}, {a, b, c, d, m, n, l, k}]` ?  $\{1260,1435,1530,6880\}$

Comment: @WReach Yes. That is odd.  I placed `3` in position `b` in all locations and removed it from the variables and it still does not find it.  Has a bug been found?

Comment: The `Sort` is being resolved too early -- the effective condition is `{a, b, c, d} == {k, l, m, n}`.  I have yet to find an alternate formulation that both works and runs in reasonable time.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply try all $x$ and $y$ pairs:

```
n = 2;

nDigitIntegers = Range[10^(n - 1), 10^n - 1];

vampireNumbersQ = Function[{x, y},
   IntegerLength[x*y] == 2 n && 
    Sort[IntegerDigits[x + y*10^n]] == Sort[IntegerDigits[x*y]]];

xy = Flatten[Table[
      If[vampireNumbersQ[x, y],
       {x, y} -> x*y, {}],
      {x, nDigitIntegers}, {y, nDigitIntegers[[1]], x}
     ]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0327479, Null}

```
xy
```

> {{15, 93} -> 1395, {21, 60} -> 1260, {21, 87} -> 1827, {27, 81} -> 
>     2187, {30, 51} -> 1530, {35, 41} -> 1435, {80, 86} -> 6880}

at least for small numbers, this is very fast. I can find all 2-digit vampire numbers in 0.03 seconds. For `n=3` it takes about 3s to find:

> {387*351==135837, 401*260==104260, 401*350==140350, 410*323==132430, 410*350==143500, 414*351==145314, 414*396==163944, 422*311==131242, 423*315==133245, 425*317==134725, 431*356==153436, 443*281==124483, 461*317==146137, 470*371==174370, 486*261==126846, 491*395==193945, 500*251==125500, 501*210==105210, 501*300==150300, 510*201==102510, 510*246==125460, 510*300==153000, 516*204==105264, 524*461==241564, 534*231==123354, 542*470==254740, 543*231==125433, 581*269==156289, 581*422==245182, 582*489==284598, 585*261==152685, 588*231==135828, 591*327==193257, 591*534==315594, 600*201==120600, 600*210==126000, 602*437==263074, 608*251==152608, 612*468==286416, 615*204==125460, 623*524==326452, 626*341==213466, 627*201==126027, 630*585==368550, 635*215==136525, 635*530==336550, 641*533==341653, 650*281==182650, 650*641==416650, 651*240==156240, 662*593==392566, 671*323==216733, 678*321==217638, 678*420==284760, 686*533==365638, 692*338==233896, 701*158==110758, 701*167==117067, 704*650==457600, 705*150==105750, 707*431==304717, 719*275==197725, 725*161==116725, 725*179==129775, 725*350==253750, 725*431==312475, 750*231==173250, 759*231==175329, 759*681==516879, 761*152==115672, 780*624==486720, 782*221==172822, 800*473==378400, 801*135==108135, 801*225==180225, 801*252==201852, 806*323==260338, 807*255==205785, 810*225==182250, 810*270==218700, 822*276==226872, 824*152==125248, 831*465==386415, 834*570==475380, 840*141==118440, 840*546==458640, 842*269==226498, 845*491==414895, 845*590==498550, 846*540==456840, 851*296==251896, 855*630==538650, 860*251==215860, 860*800==688000, 863*392==338296, 864*216==186624, 864*657==567648, 870*210==182700, 870*435==378450, 875*650==568750, 876*843==738468, 878*431==378418, 881*248==218488, 890*482==428980, 891*432==384912, 891*468==416988, 891*549==489159, 897*201==180297, 899*545==489955, 900*351==315900, 902*875==789250, 906*210==190260, 906*750==679500, 906*894==809964, 908*446==404968, 909*351==319059, 909*891==809919, 915*210==192150, 926*140==129640, 926*176==162976, 926*248==229648, 926*284==262984, 926*320==296320, 926*356==329656, 926*392==362992, 926*464==429664, 926*572==529672, 926*680==629680, 926*788==729688, 926*896==829696, 927*855==792585, 930*150==139500, 936*360==336960, 936*720==673920, 938*146==136948, 941*476==447916, 942*156==146952, 945*891==841995, 948*366==346968, 951*165==156915, 951*336==319536, 951*588==559188, 951*858==815958, 953*563==536539, 957*825==789525, 963*342==329346, 963*765==736695, 969*381==369189, 971*383==371893, 975*321==312975, 981*216==211896, 981*369==361989, 983*650==638950, 984*807==794088, 986*953==939658, 992*776==769792}

I haven't tried `n=4`, but it should take about 300s, as it has to check 100 times as many combinations.

Answer (score 4):

Been a while since I participated on this site; don't get to use *Mathematica* that often either.

Figured I'd post this (not particularly fast) solution anyway:

```
vQ[n_ /; EvenQ@IntegerLength@n] := 
  (Times @@FromDigits /@ {#[[;; (IntegerLength@n)/2]], #[[(IntegerLength@n)/2 + 1 ;;]]} & 
  /@ Permutations[IntegerDigits[n]])~MemberQ~n

vQ[_]:=False
```