# Finding the largest palindrome which is the product of two 2-digit numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, integer-sequence, palindrome

My goal is to find the largest palindrome which is the product of two 2-digit numbers using the following program. I want the program to add each palindrome it finds, to the list H. I also want it to test all $n$ from $10$ to $99$, on each respective value of $m$ from $10$ to $99$. Where is the error in the following code?

```
Clear[H];
H = {};
n = 10;
Do[While[n < 100, 
   If[PalindromeQ[n*m], H = Append[H, m*n]; n = n + 1, 
    n = n + 1]], {m, 10, 99}];
Max[H]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be made to work with one minor change. You must initialize `n` at each step of your Do-loop.

```
H = {};
Do[
  n = 10; 
  While[n < 100, 
    If[PalindromeQ[n*m], H = Append[H, m*n]; n = n + 1, n = n + 1]], 
  {m, 10, 99}]
Max[H]
```

> `9009`

Staying with procedural methods, I would would still recommend searching in the other direction, large products to small, as a better approach. With that approach you can break out the loops as soon as you find the 1st palindromic integer. The following code is simpler and faster than yours.

```
Module[{m, n, result},
  result = $Failed;
  m = 99;
  While[m > 0,
    n = 99;
    While[n > 0,
      If[PalindromeQ[n m], result = n m; n = 0; m = 0];
      n--];
    m--];
 result]
```

> `9009`

Answer (score 1):

```
sub = Subsets[Range[10, 99], {2}];

res = Last@Select[Times @@@ sub, IntegerDigits[#] == Reverse@IntegerDigits[#] &]
```

> 9009

```
Extract[sub, FirstPosition[Times @@@ sub, res]]
```

> {91, 99}

Comment: Replace `Permutations[Range[10, 99], {2}]` with `Subsets[Range[10, 99], {2}]` to reduce the search space (multiplication is commutative). If you're already on version 10.3 or higher, use `PalindromeQ[]` for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `Subsets`. - Still on V10

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DivisorPairs[n]` from a [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15094/generating-the-list-of-factors-and-summands-for-an-integer) by Mr.Wizard to find two numbers whose product is `n`.

```
DivisorPairs[n_] :=
   Thread[{#, Reverse[#]}][[ ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]] &[Divisors[n]]
```

The second helper function `twoDigitProductQ[n]` tests that both elements in the pair have 2 digits.

```
twoDigitProductQ[n_] := 
   DeleteDuplicates[
      Pick[#, IntegerLength[#], {2, 2}] &[DivisorPairs[n]]] =!= {{}}
```

Now count down from the maximum as @m_goldberg suggests.

```
Do[
   If[PalindromeQ[n] && twoDigitProductQ[n], Return[n]],
   {n, 99*99, 1, -1}]
```

> 9009