# Highlighting bracketing in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, formatting, syntax-highlighting

I'm working with lists of lists of lists. Each box with information has a specific format like

```
  information = {{a},{{b}},{{{c},{d}},{e,{f}}},{g}}
```

and so together they look like

```
  {{{a},{{b}},{{{c},{d}},{e,{f}}},{g}},{{h},{{i}},{{{j},{k}},{l,{m}}},{n}},...
```

and this goes over the whole screen.

I want to make the inner and outer brackets in an expression like **{{** a **}}** look different, possibly down to all levels. Is there a way to highlight the bracketing in such a way that I can *see* the different levels of the list?

Comment: Mathematica 9 highlights matching brackets when your cursor is at either of them. I would however in such a situation ask the question "why is this structure so complicated" and "Can it be made simpler". If for instance you are making implied assumptions such as "the third argument is a list of lists of number of animals and corresponding weight in a list". Then you can typically make everything much simpler by rethinking how you handle your data. In cases where you are in fact dealing with complex structures consider making a dynamic input gizmo for it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776158/matching-brackets-in-a-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461688/how-do-i-get-auto-conversion-of-part-double-brackets-on-paste

Comment: @Szabolcs: I agree on the duplicate.

Comment: @Ajasja The only problem is that the other question doesn't have a general solution yet.  The existing answer is only for special cases.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Interesting reference, although I was not thinking of a function like *TraditionalForm*, but I want to have the input data displayed differently when I type it in. I'll never evaluate the data as such, I convert the "information" to something differen, see next post.

Comment: @jVincent: The information is [chemical data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14883/generating-a-function-which-outputs-possible-chemical-reactions) (the version of the code in that question is not up to date). I e.g. print it in some sort of TeX-Form. Don't know how to reduce the boxes to a more pleasurable form atm.

Comment: My [code highlighter generator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles/1320#1320) could do this with some tweaking. Unfortunately, I did not make the bracket - matchings and highlighting routines customizable enough to incorporate coloring brackets on different levels with different colors, so some changes to the code are needed to implement this.